# DOM insertion in jQuery 1.8 causes javascript triggering twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

HTML:

```
<div id="container">prepend to me</div>
<div id="event">Event Here<script>alert('Fired');</script></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').prepend($('#event'));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ckfs5/1/
Switching to jQuery 1.9 or higher seems to fix the problem.

Is there a workaround so javascript doesn't trigger again during DOM insertion (using prepend or append) in jQuery 1.8?

Upgrading to jQuery 1.9 or newer will be a more difficult path, as we're using this on a big project. So I'm hoping to find a solution / workaround for this problem in jQuery 1.8.3.

Comment: the javascript should fire twice in your example.  Once from the #event div already on the page, and once when its prepended.  Also, this will cause an id conflict!

Comment: @Rooster Why would it cause an ID conflict? `prepend` doesn't make a copy, it moves the element to the new location.

Comment: @Barmar oh good point.  I made an assumption how it worked without looking at the doc +1.  The first part of my comment still applies though.  For the op, I guess one way around this behavior would be to set a global flag upon the first fire that prevents a second fire of the code, or some such.

Comment: @Rooster: This behaviour doens't happen in jQuery 1.9 and higher.

Comment: @RadiusKuntoro I'm too lazy to look at the actual source, but I would guess that prior to 1.9, prepend worked by copying the element, deleting the old, then inserting the copy as a new element, which would trigger the current behavior.  And after 1.9 it was probably refactored with this situation in mind.

Comment: @Rooster, that would be a valid explanation... I tested the native JS equivalent `document.body.insertBefore(document.getElementById('event'), document.getElementById('container'))` and this worked as expected, firing only once. Perhaps the solution is to use native JS for these lines

Comment: @Rooster: Thanks for the clues. I'm able to come up with a fix by borrowing the newer jquery code.

Answer (score 3):

This will remove any embedded scripts before prepending to the new location:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').prepend($('#event').find("script").remove().end());
});
```

The scripts presumably only needed to run when the page was first loaded, so removing them at this point should not be a problem.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Ckfs5/3/)

Comment: I've considered this solution. It fixes the problem in the demo, but there are a lot of other useful scripts like event listeners that I cannot afford to get rid of in the actual project.

Comment: I don't think removing the script tag has any effect on event listeners that were already established by the script. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Ckfs5/4/ It calls a function that was in the removed tag.

Answer (score 1):

Solution by Tyblitz:

Use insertBefore and vanilla JS:

```
document.body.insertBefore(document.getElementById('event'), document.getElementById('container'));
```

jQuery fix solution:

Borrowing from newer jQuery codes:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    prependnew: function() {
        return this.domManip( arguments, function( elem ) {
            if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 || this.nodeType === 9 ) {
                var target = manipulationTarget( this, elem );
                target.insertBefore( elem, target.firstChild );
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Also copy the new domManip function.